# В PyCharm не пропадают уведомления проблем во вкладке Problems после их исправления в коде

Tags: python, pycharm, python-3.12

В PyCharm не пропадают уведомления проблем во вкладке Problems после их исправления в коде.. Началось недавно, ранее они пропадали сразу после исправления в коде.
Как исправить помогите.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Три варианта:

1. Переключи раскладку на английскую, затем нажми Ctrl-s
2. Просто перезагрузи пайчарм
3. Создай новый проект. Если вы полностью изменили код то это может вызвать этот баг

Comment: Как может помочь переключение раскладки?

Comment: потому что если раскладка будет русская и ты нажмешь контрол с(англ) то это будеть контрол+ы

Comment: @Ioann у PyCharm и других продуктов JetBrains нет проблем с раскладкой. Даже если в поиске начнешь искать не в той раскладке, он найдет в правильной

Comment: Не пойму в чем причина. В некоторых файлах проекта все норм, а в некоторых такая проблема. Если файл уже не новый и ошибки я сам убирал из окна то потом вроде все в порядке. А до этого висит ошибка даже если ее исправил...может где-то настройки сбились, пока не пойму.